# Install Windows 7 from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, windows-7

I need to install Windows 7 on an Ubuntu PC (and remove Ubuntu), but this PC doesn't have any CD reader. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Buy a CD reader. :D

Comment: :) I may have an option with the USB drive, but haven't found the tool to build an ISO with Ubuntu

Comment: Seriously now, it will give you a lot of trouble, especially if you plan to remove Ubuntu afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a good walkthrough](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-windows-7-from-ubuntu-without-burnning-a-disc)

So the steps:

1. Download grub4dos
2. Create a NTFS partition and mount the ISO (sudo mount /path/to/your/iso /mnt -o loop)
3. Edit the grub according to your partition
4. Reboot from the NTFS partition.

   grub>find --set-root /bootmgr

   grub>chainloader /bootmgr

   grub>boot
5. Run setup.exe

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While it may be a great link, could you summarize what the OP needs to do rather than just linking? You should keep the link as a source, of course.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me : I have only one partition (linux) and the usual swap partition with it. So I can't create a new partition without deleting the linux one (not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if (as you've said) you have the boot-from-USB option in the BIOS, it should be easy to write the Windows ISO (assuming you have one) onto a USB stick. You can use the built-in software `usb-creator`

In case you don't have it, type in terminal `sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk`

Then from the Windows install menu, you can easily format the whole drive and install Windows as a single partition.